# MigLayout row-height and changing font-size

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, miglayout

I have a problem using MigLayout in combination with dynamically changing the font-size of the components which are shown in the MigLayout cells.

In detail: I added a JCheckBox via MigLayout to a JPanel. The font-size of the JCheckBox is default (12pt?) and the row which contains the JCheckBox has a preferred height of 17lp. That all works fine.
(View here: http://www.bilderload.com/bild/227327/migproblemcellheight1UQXP2.png)

Now I change the font-size to e.g. 20pt and start the program again. Now the text of the JCheckBox is cut because the row has also the height of 17lp.
(View here: http://www.bilderload.com/bild/227328/migproblemcellheight2DDPGJ.png)

If I for example let the row definition empty ("[]") the text shows correctly with both font sizes - the normal and the large one. But in this case the row will sadly never reach a minimum of 17lp. (It will always have a minimum of 23lp or so)

How can I change the MigLayout definition to get a minimum row-height of 17lp and to let the cell grow correctly with the components font-size/text etc.?
Or maybe this is a L&F problem?

Thanks & best regards,

Philipp

Here is my sample code (working example):

```
import java.awt.Font;

import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;

public class TestMigLayoutFontSize extends JFrame {
  public TestMigLayoutFontSize() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(600, 400);
    setContentPane(getTestPanel());
    setVisible(true);
  }

  private JPanel getTestPanel() {
    JCheckBox testBox = new JCheckBox("Program argument");
    Font normalFont = testBox.getFont();
    Font largeFont = new Font(testBox.getFont().getName(), testBox.getFont().getStyle(), 20);
    // testBox.setFont(normalFont);
    testBox.setFont(largeFont);

    JPanel tempPanel = new JPanel(new MigLayout("debug", "0lp![grow,fill]0lp!", "[17lp:17lp:n]"));
    tempPanel.add(testBox);

    JPanel testPanel = new JPanel(new MigLayout("", "[grow,fill]", "[grow,fill]"));
    testPanel.add(tempPanel);

    return testPanel;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new TestMigLayoutFontSize();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may reduce the space around your checkbox by reducing the border size, e.g. put

```
testBox.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(1, 1, 1, 1));
```

directly after the assignment of `testBox`. You may then leave the row definition empty and still get a reasonable height for your panel.

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me. I think the problem is , that you specify the preferred size.

Regards 
 Roger

```
package de.test;

import java.awt.Font;

import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;

public class MigTest extends JFrame {
  public MigTest() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(600, 400);
    setContentPane(getTestPanel());
    setVisible(true);
  }

  private JPanel getTestPanel() {
    JCheckBox testBox = new JCheckBox("Program argument");
    Font normalFont = testBox.getFont();
    Font largeFont = new Font(testBox.getFont().getName(), testBox.getFont().getStyle(), 90);
    // testBox.setFont(normalFont);
    testBox.setFont(largeFont);

    JPanel tempPanel = new JPanel(new MigLayout("debug", "0lp![grow,fill]0lp!", "[80:n:]"));
    tempPanel.add(testBox);

    JPanel testPanel = new JPanel(new MigLayout("", "[grow,fill]", "[grow,fill]"));
    testPanel.add(tempPanel);

    return testPanel;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new MigTest();
  }
}
```